# How to call a function in Javascript on pressing the "Enter" key

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox but I can't figure out a way, so that it calls a javascript function present in the same file.

```
<input type="text" style="width: 30px" disabled id="mybid" name="" value="" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 13) myFunction();second(1);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabled elements can't gain the focus. Inputs cannot have child elements.

There is no way for the user to trigger a `keyup` event on the input.

Remove the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: Yeah i removed it , but it wasn't of any help.

Comment: It [works fine](http://jsbin.com/lekuhafu/1/edit) if you remove the attribute. If yours does not, then the cause of the problem is not described in your question.

Comment: thanks i added this code and it worked for me with the disabled attribute

    document.getElementById("mybid").addEventListener( "keydown", function( e ) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if ( keyCode === 13 ) {
       // enter pressed
 myFunction();
       secon(1);
    }
}, false);